# Php creating image thumb with fixed width and height

Tags: php, image-processing, thumbnails

Guys i know that this question is asked before but its not the same because i have tried others answers and nothing worked as I want.

I want to create thumbnail image using php and the thumbnail **width="265px"** and **height="125px"** and here is my code :

```
$image_width = $imageSize[0];
$image_height = $imageSize[1];

$new_size = ($image_width + $image_height) / ($image_width * ($image_height / 45));         //this will set any image to 125*70 which is a good thumbnail

$new_width = $image_width * $new_size;
$new_height = $image_height * $new_size;

if($ext == "gif"){ 
    $old_image = imagecreatefromgif($real_image_path);
}else if($ext =="png"){ 
    $old_image = imagecreatefrompng($real_image_path);
}else{ 
    $old_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($real_image_path);
}

$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);                                                     //creating new image with a new color for quality

imagecopyresized($new_image, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $image_width, $image_height);
```

I am not very sure about my comments but i just wrote them just in case

I think it need someone that is good in maths

Thanks and happy new year

Comment: And exactly how is this not working for you...?

Comment: here's a hint.. you don't need math to resize an image..

Comment: @MarcB it doesn't get the size that I want

Comment: @Pamblam I thought it need an equation or ratio to resize any width and any height to a fixed one

Comment: not for a fixed height AND width.. if you wanted to scale the image you would need math, but you're not scaling anything, you're resizing it and potentially changing the aspect ratio..

Comment: plus the math you're doing doesn't make much sense. if you want to proportionally resize the image, doing `height + width` makes no sense. you do `heigh/width` to get an aspect ration, then use that ratio to the final sizes based on what your target size is.

Comment: I am not good in maths and also @Pamblam is right i need fixed width and height :D
thank you guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No math required..

```
if($ext == "gif"){ 
    $old_image = imagecreatefromgif($real_image_path);
}else if($ext =="png"){ 
    $old_image = imagecreatefrompng($real_image_path);
}else{ 
    $old_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($real_image_path);
}
$data = getimagesize($real_image_path);

$height = 125;
$width = 265;
$thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagealphablending($thumb, false);
imagesavealpha($thumb, true);
imagecopyresampled($thumb, $old_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $data[0], $data[1]);
```

Comment: exactly what I want.. I didn't know that i could enter the width and height like this